# How to achieve this. Help me

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-development

1. 

(Lead Status - Open)
If the lead is still in the same condition(open) after 5 hours of lead creation, an email has to be sent to the owner of the lead and the manager of the owner in  email CC.

I have created batch class like this but it is sending email to owner not manager. I want both.

```
public class OpenLeadEmailBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        // Query for leads with status Open created 5 hours ago or earlier
        DateTime cutoffTime = DateTime.now().addHours(-5);
        String query = 'SELECT Id, OwnerId, Owner.Email ,Owner.Manager.Email FROM Lead WHERE Status__c = \'Open\' AND CreatedDate <= :cutoffTime';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Lead> scope) {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        
        for (Lead lead : scope) {
            // Create email for lead owner
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailToOwner = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            emailToOwner.setToAddresses(new String[]{ lead.Owner.Email });
         //   emailToOwner.setCCAddresses(new String[]{ lead.Owner.Manager.Email }); //set the manager email id field
            emailToOwner.setSubject('Open Lead Reminder');
            emailToOwner.setPlainTextBody('This is a reminder that the lead with ID: ' + lead.Id + ' is still open.');
            emails.add(emailToOwner);
            
                    }
        
        // Send the emails
        if (!emails.isEmpty()) {
            Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
        }
    }
    
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
      
    }
    
}
```

(Lead Status - Open)
If the lead is still in the same condition(open) after 5 hours of lead creation, an email has to be sent to the owner of the lead and the manager of the owner in  email CC.

I have created batch class like this but it is sending email to owner not manager. I want both.

Comment: Please choose a non-generic title that describes your specific problem. Thanks.